# U++ and "TheIDE" fatal error: 7CtrlLib/CtrlLib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, testing, user-interface, compilation

Trying to compile test examples in U++ however they're failing to compile, this error is displayed:

```
----- helloworld ( MAIN GCC DEBUG SHARED DEBUG_FULL BLITZ LINUX POSIX ) main.cpp /home/testbed/upp/uppsrc/helloworld/main.cpp:1:30: fatal
error: 7CtrlLib/CtrlLib.h: No such file or directory compilation
terminated. helloworld: 1 file(s) built in (0:00.34), 342 msecs /
file, duration = 345 msecs

There were errors. (0:00.36)
```

What do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the compiler cannot find the file `7CtrlLib/CtrlLib.h`. Do you miss this file in your includes folder?

Comment: How do I do this? I am an utter noob at programming

Comment: The verbose error message is over 2300 characters too long for this:

cd /home/testbed/upp/uppsrc/helloworld
main.cpp
g++ -c  -I"/home/testbed/upp/uppsrc" -I"/usr/include/freetype2" -I"/usr/include/gtk-2.0" -I"/usr/include/glib-2.0" -I"/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include" -I"/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include" -I"/usr/include/cairo" -I"/usr/include
 /pango-1.0" -I"/usr/include/atk-1.0" -I"/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0" -I"/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include" -I"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include" -I"/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include" -I"
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include" -I"/usr/include

Comment: ^^that's as much as I can type, hopefully that's enough info?

Comment: /home/testbed/upp/uppsrc/helloworld/main.cpp:1:29: fatal error: CtrlLib/CtrlLib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated

Answer (score 0):

> `main.cpp:1:30: fatal error: 7CtrlLib/CtrlLib.h: No such file or directory`

This seems like there is a typo in your code in #include on the first line of main.cpp. The '7' shouldn't be there. If there is no such typing error, please post complete verbose output form the compilation (check Setup -> Be Verbose && compile again).